# Displaying the data held within a method in TextView

Tags: java, android, methods, textview

Just an issue about using a method within TextView.

Using Java, I wrote out a fixture list (in a separate Fixture class) for weeks 1 to 7 that would work out football scores. The scores would be held in an array in which I would create an instance of the Fixtures class and display the results. This works fine on the standard Eclipse console output but having issues putting it into practice in Android.

I believe the problem is in the conversion,as normally I would use String.valueOf to convert to string for TextView output. However this does not work with my current method. Here is the code so far:

```
package com.example.papersoccer;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Fixtures fixtures = new Fixtures();
    String[] teamResults = new String[8];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onClickGoToLeagueSummary(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void onClickDisplayResults(View view)
    {
        TextView txtDisplayResults;
        txtDisplayResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDisplayResults);
        fixtures.teamFixturesW1(teamResults);
        txtDisplayResults.setText(String.valueOf(fixtures.teamFixturesW1(teamResults)));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

There is a red error line underscoring "String.valueOf". I suspect it cannot convert a method to string. Is there an alternative to this that will display the data held in the method to TextView?

EDIT:
This is the code of all my 4 games included in the method if it helps anyone.

```
package com.example.papersoccer;

import java.util.Random;


public class Fixtures 
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int resultHome = 0; //stores home team result
    int resultAway = 0; //stores away team result
    String[] myTeams = new String[8]; //stores an array of string teams
    int[] goalsScored = new int[8]; //stores an int array of goals each team scored
    int[] pointsAttained = new int[8]; //stores an int array of points attained by each team



    public void teamFixturesW1(String[] teamResults)
    {
        myTeams[0] = "Manchester Utd"; //A
        myTeams[1] = "AC Milan"; //B
        myTeams[2] = "Celtic Fc"; //C
        myTeams[3] = "Shakhtar Donestk"; //D
        myTeams[4] = "Juventus"; //E
        myTeams[5] = "Chelsea"; //F
        myTeams[6] = "Barcelona"; //G
        myTeams[7] = "Real Madrid"; //H

        //1st Game
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            //assign variables random generated numbers
            resultHome = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
            resultAway = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
        System.out.println(myTeams[2] + " " + resultHome + " " + "- " + resultAway + " " + myTeams[3]);
        //set conditions for win, loss and draw
        if (resultHome > resultAway)
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[2] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[2] += 3; //add 3 points for a win
            goalsScored[2] += resultHome; //increment goals by home team
            goalsScored[3] += resultAway; //increment goals scored by away team
        }
        else if(resultAway > resultHome) //set condition for away team win
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[3] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[3] += 3;
            goalsScored[2] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[3] += resultAway;
        }
        else if(resultHome == resultAway) //set condition for draw
        {
            System.out.println("Both teams draw and go away with 1 point each!!\n");
            pointsAttained[2] +=1;
            pointsAttained[3] +=1;
            goalsScored[2] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[3] += resultAway;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Game abandoned due to severe weather conditions."); //game postponed
        }
        }

        //2nd Game
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            //assign variables random generated numbers
            resultHome = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
            resultAway = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
        System.out.println(myTeams[7] + " " + resultHome + " " + "- " + resultAway + " " + myTeams[0]);
        //set conditions for win, loss and draw
        if (resultHome > resultAway)
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[7] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[7] += 3; //add 3 points for a win
            goalsScored[7] += resultHome; //increment scored by home team
            goalsScored[0] += resultAway; //increment goals scored by away team
        }
        else if(resultAway > resultHome) //set condition for away team win
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[0] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[0] += 3;
            goalsScored[7] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[0] += resultAway;
        }
        else if(resultHome == resultAway) //set condition for draw
        {
            System.out.println("Both teams draw and go away with 1 point each!!\n");
            pointsAttained[7] +=1;
            pointsAttained[0] +=1;
            goalsScored[7] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[0] += resultAway;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Game abandoned due to severe weather conditions."); //game postponed
        }
        }





        //3rd game
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            //assign variables random generated numbers
            resultHome = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
            resultAway = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
        System.out.println(myTeams[6] + " " + resultHome + " " + "- " + resultAway + " " + myTeams[4]);
        //set conditions for win, loss and draw
        if (resultHome > resultAway)
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[6] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[6] += 3; //add 3 points for a win
            goalsScored[6] += resultHome; //increment scored by home team
            goalsScored[4] += resultAway; //increment goals scored by away team
        }
        else if(resultAway > resultHome) //set condition for away team win
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[4] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[4] += 3;
            goalsScored[6] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[4] += resultAway;
        }
        else if(resultHome == resultAway) //set condition for draw
        {
            System.out.println("Both teams draw and go away with 1 point each!!\n");
            pointsAttained[6] +=1;
            pointsAttained[4] +=1;
            goalsScored[6] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[4] += resultAway;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Game abandoned due to severe weather conditions."); //game postponed
        }
       }





        //4th game
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            //assign variables random generated numbers
            resultHome = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
            resultAway = random.nextInt(0 + 4);
        System.out.println(myTeams[5] + " " + resultHome + " " + "- " + resultAway + " " + myTeams[1]);
        //set conditions for win, loss and draw
        if (resultHome > resultAway)
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[5] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[5] += 3; //add 3 points for a win
            goalsScored[5] += resultHome; //increment scored by home team
            goalsScored[1] += resultAway; //increment goals scored by away team
        }
        else if(resultAway > resultHome) //set condition for away team win
        {
            System.out.println(myTeams[1] + " have clinched 3 points in an epic game!!\n");
            pointsAttained[1] += 3;
            goalsScored[5] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[1] += resultAway;
        }
        else if(resultHome == resultAway) //set condition for draw
        {
            System.out.println(" Both teams draw and go away with 1 point each!!\n");
            pointsAttained[5] +=1;
            pointsAttained[1] +=1;
            goalsScored[5] += resultHome;
            goalsScored[1] += resultAway;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Game abandoned due to severe weather conditions."); //game postponed
        }
     }

    }//end of method
```

I understand it is very poorly written but I will fix once I understand OOP better.

Comment: what does fixtures.teamFixturesW1() return?

Comment: A String Array I think. I am new to Java and OOP so I have not got my head quite around it but I could post the code for you if you want?

Comment: yeah, maybe post the code if you can

Comment: I edited the post to take into account for my method code. Team names are held in string arrays and points they earn (including goals scored) are stored in integer arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There look to be a couple of mistakes in your `teamFixturesW1()` method:

1. The method is defined as returning `void` - which is the cause of the issue in the OP, you can't call `String.valueOf(null)`
2. the `String[] teamResults` you pass into the method is never used - is this intended?

I think to fix your issue you should do something like the following:

```
public String teamFixturesW1(String[] teamResults){
    String results = "";

    ...

    return results;
}
```

and then fill the `results` String with any data that you want to display in the `TextView`

Comment: Thanks. Going to try this out just now.

Comment: Does not work I am afraid. It just returns whatever value you assign to the string. I think the String[] teamResults returns the team array values to the main activity class. I will update my code in my question to take account of the variables and arrays I used if that will help you?

Comment: the String[] teamResults is never used, you don't assign anything to it, so even if it was passing something back to the MainActivity class, it would be empty. I'm not sure what you're wanting the method to be returning, can you clarify that?

Comment: In all honesty, I am unsure. My methods consist of integers and strings so I have thrown myself into confusion and may have approached the algorithm the wrong way. Although looking at it, I think the primary intent is to return integers for points and goals obtained by each club. I just wanted to align the points and goals with the clubs in the string array.